# Setting font protrusion in XeLaTeX with microtype v2.5

Tags: xetex, microtype, protrusion

I am testing `microtype v2.5` with `XeLaTeX` and have checked the font protrusion features. With the default features, the hyphen protrudes at a hyphenation about 50 per cent of its width. Nonetheless, I'd like to increase the protrusion factor for this character when setting text with the default roman font, and I have tried by typing in the preamble

```
\SetProtrusion{encoding=*,family=rm*}{"002D={1000,1000}}
```

expecting to get full-width protrusion, but nothing changed. I have also typed directly the hyphen sign - instead of its unicode value 002D (hex), in the code above, but it remained the same. Furthermore, no matter the factor figures I set, nothing seems to change. I may be using the wrong code, but if so, how could I amend it?

EDIT: After having commented upon Honza's answer I checked that the way to refer to unicode glyphs in terms of their hexadecimal encoding is not the TeX way as in \char"002D, but simply "002D without the control sequence `\char`. Moreover, just in case someone stumbles upon it, in order to set the protrusion factor for a comma it seems that the unicode "002C must be used -- the character "," itself won't do (maybe because it is used as a delimiter in the `microtype` command).

Comment: Please post an MWE that generates the unwanted behavior you're trying to address.

Comment: The microtype package v2.4 (the current version that is available for me) does not work with XeTeX.

Comment: @HiggsBoson you can find a beta version of v2.5. at tlcontrib: http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be in the character you are trying to adjust. With the hex specification `\char"002D` the protrusion does not work for me, however, if I replace it with `-`, which I copied out from the PDF, or a regular hyphen `-`, it works without problems.

Comment: I tried an MWE using only `memoir` as class, together with the packages `fontspec`, `microtype`, and `lipsum`, and there it was. I had been using this in a class of my own loading many different packages, and it didn't work. After checking the MWE, I tried loading `microtype` as the last package in my class, and then it worked. Hence, it was all about the package loading arrangement. I'm afraid I cannot tell what packages were colliding with `microtype`, but it was solved like that. Honza's is the right answer anyway if we stick to the question I post. Thanks so much to everyone.